# Pointer to a class instance in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

Is it possible to store the reference to a class instance?

```
class Node
{
    public int id;
    public int value;
    public List<Node> neighbours;
}
```

How do I populate the list `neighbours` in such a way that any changes I make to a `Node` instance will be reflected there ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
public List<Node> neighbours;
```

Since your `Node` class is a reference type all variables of type `Node` will only contain *references* (just like a pointer) to a `Node` object in memory - so the neighbours list contains a list of *references* to your `Node` objects- any change to those objects will be reflected in the list, since they point to the objects that you modified.

Also see [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> A data type is a value type if it
>   holds the data within its own memory
>   allocation. A reference type contains
>   a pointer to another memory location
>   that holds the data.

**Edit** to address comment:

As mentioned your `Node` class is a reference type, all class types are. I quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) again:

> Structs may seem similar to classes,
>   but there are important differences
>   that you should be aware of. First of
>   all, classes are reference types and
>   structs are value types. By using
>   structs, you can create objects that
>   behave like the built-in types and
>   enjoy their benefits as well.

Now what does that mean for you? The size of a `struct` type is the combined size of its members, it does not point to a memory address, unlike the `class` type. Using a  `struct` will change the semantics of your type's behavior - if you assign one struct instance to another of the same type (same for any other value type), all values in the `struct` will be copied from one to the other, **you still have two separate object instances**. - for a reference type on the other hand both would **point to the same object** afterwards.

**Example** Node is a `class`:

```
Node node1 = new Node() { id = 1, value = 42};
Node node2 = node1;

node2.value = 55;
Console.WriteLine(node1.value); //prints 55, both point to same,modified object
```

**Example** Node is a `struct`:

```
Node node1 = new Node() { id = 1, value = 42};
Node node2 = node1;

node2.value = 55;
Console.WriteLine(node1.value); //prints 42, separate objects
```

Comment: +1. One detail is missing in this otherwise nice answer: I think it would be good to point out that `class` creates a reference type, while `struct` creates a value type. Pointing out this difference might be esp. useful for people coming from C++, since the difference between `class`/`struct` is a different one there and the full meaning of these keywords in C# might not be obvious for them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
Node node = new Node{Id =1, Value = 1};
node.neighbours = new List<Node>();
Node neighbourNode = new Node{Id =1, Value = 1};
node.neighbours.Add(neighbourNode);
```

you can change `neighbourNode` after adding it to `node` and since you are storing the reference, it will be reflected in the list's item.